# Is it possible to dynamically create an array of constant size in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator

First of all, I want to reassure you all that I am asking this question out of curiosity. I mean, don't tell me that if I need this then my design has problems because I don't need this in real code. Hope I convinced you :) Now to the question:

For most types T we can write

```
T* p = new T;
```

now what if T is an array type?

```
int (*p)[3] =  new ???; //pointer to array of 3 = new ???
```

I tried this:

```
typedef int arr[3];
arr* p = new arr;
```

but this doesn't work.

Is there any valid syntax for this or it is impossible in C++. If it is impossible, then why? Thanks

***Edit***: i am guessing I wasn't clear enough. I want to be able to use it in this situation:

```
void f(int(&)[3]);
int (*p)[3] = new ???;
f(*p);
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to know if C++ has a way to "infer" the size of the array without explicitly specifying it in the allocation?

Comment: @oakley: not quite: I am asking if I an use `T* p = mew T;` syntax when T is an array type (with compile-time-known dimension)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason you can't do it is that `new int[3]` already allocates exactly what you want, an object of type `int[3]`. It's just that what the new-expression *returns*, is a pointer to its first element. 5.3.4/1:

> If the entity is a non-array object,
>   the new-expression returns a pointer
>   to the object created. If it is an
>   array, the new-expression returns a
>   pointer to the initial element of the
>   array.

Returning a pointer to the first element is what allows the `3` to be unknown until runtime, so I suppose that by knowing it in advance, you've tripped over flexibility that you aren't using.

I guess the ways around this are to reinterpret_cast back to the pointer type you want (not necessarily portable), or to allocate a struct containing an `int[3]` (and use a pointer to its data member).

[Edit: er, yeah, or FredOverflow's idea, which has neither disadvantage, but requires use of `delete[]` instead of `delete`.]

I guess the moral is, if you write templates that naively allocate some unknown type `T` with `new`, then the template won't work when someone passes an array type as `T`. You'll be assigning it to the wrong pointer type, and if you fix that (perhaps with `auto`), you'll be deleting it wrongly.

Edit in answer to j_kubik's question:

Here's one way to distinguish between array and non-array types. If you write a function like this, that returns an object that holds the pointer and is capable of correctly deleting it, then you have a generic new/delete for any type T.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void make_thing_helper(T *) {
    std::cout << "plain version\n";
}

template <typename T, int N>
void make_thing_helper(T (*)[N]) {
    std::cout << "array version\n";
}

template <typename T>
void make_thing() {
    make_thing_helper((T*)0);
}

int main() {
    typedef int T1;
    typedef int T2[3];
    make_thing<T1>();
    make_thing<T2>();
}
```

Comment: Both `new int[3]` and `new int[1][3]` have to be released via `delete[]`.

Comment: @FredOverflow: indeed, I meant "instead of" what happens with a non-array type. If I was inventing the magic non-existent syntax that Armen wants, to allocate a single object of array type *as though* it were a non-array type, then it would let you delete it with `delete` through the same pointer that's returned from `MagicNew`. So it'd look like `typedef int arr[3]; arr *p = MagicNew arr; delete p;`. I know he didn't specify this in his question, maybe it was wrong of me to assume that others would invent it the same way.

Comment: So to summarize - is there a way to make new-delete template ready for array types or is it simply impossible?

Comment: @J_kubik: I think you could do it, but you need to distinguish whether `T` is an array type or not somewhere along the way. I'll add one way of doing that to my answer.

Answer (score 11):

To get a pointer to an array from `new`, you have to dynamically allocate a two-dimensional array:

```
int (*p)[3] = new int[1][3];
```

Comment: Hmm... not quite what I was expecting but certainly my example will work... +1

Answer (score 2):

You could always use boost::array, which will be in C++0x.
Otherwise, any solution will be awkward at best: arrays are
broken in C, and C++ maintains compatilibity with C in this
respect.  Fred Overflow offered one solution; even easier (but
syntactically noisy) would be to wrap the array in a struct:
    struct A { int arr[3]; };
and allocate and manipulate this.

Comment: That would be a workaround, not a solution :) And @Fred's is too, but at least my example works with his workaround. With yours, it would't, would it?

Comment: The wrapper is a workaround, but boost:array would be my prefered solution for working with fixed size arrays.  So weird but possible: void f(array<3>& p); array<3>* p = new array<3>; f(*p);

Answer (score -2):

You just do

```
int *p = new unsigned int [3]
```

You can then use `*p` as a pointer or an array i.e. `*(p+1) or p[1]`

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't what I am asking. At all