# Is there a need to dereference when performing a memcpy using pointer to typedef fixed length array? Why or why not?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, typedef, dereference

Ok - so I'll preface this by saying I'm not entirely sure *how* to describe the question and my current confusion, so I'll do my best to provide examples.

### Question

Which of the two approaches to using the typedef-ed, fixed-length array in a memcpy call (shown below in "Context") is correct? Or are they equivalent?

(I'm starting the think that they are equivalent - some experimentation under "Notes", below).

### Context

Consider the following typedef `typedef uint8_t msgdata[150];` and the library interface `const msgdata* IRead_GetMsgData (void);` .

In my code, I use IRead_GetMsgData and memcpy the result into another uint8_t buffer (contrived example below).

```
//Included from library:
//typedef uint8_t msgdata[150];
//const msgdata* IRead_GetMsgData (void);

uint8_t mBuff[2048];
void Foo() {
    const msgdata* myData = IRead_GetMsgData();
    if(myData != nullptr) {
        std::memcpy(mBuff, *myData, sizeof(msgdata));
    }
}
```

Now, this works and passes our unit tests fine but it started a discussion between our team about whether we *should* dereference myData in this case. It turns out, not dereferencing myData also works and passes all our unit tests

```
    std::memcpy(mBuff, myData, sizeof(msgdata)); //This works fine, too
```

My thought when writing the memcpy call was that, because myData is of type msgdata*, dereferencing it would return the pointed-to msgdata, which is a uint8_t array.
E.g.

```
    typedef uint8 msgdata[150];
    msgdata mData = {0u};
    msgdata* pData = &mData;     
    memcpy(somePtr, pData, size);  //Would expect this to fail - pData isn't the buffer mData.    
    memcpy(somePtr, *pData, size); //Would expect this to work - dereferencing pData returns the buffer mData
    memcpy(somePtr, mData, size); //Would expect this to work - mData is the buffer, mData ==&mData[0]
```

I've tried searching for discussion of similar questions but haven't yet found anything that felt relevant:

- [Using new with fixed length array typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405955/using-new-with-fixed-length-array-typedef) - how to use/format a typedef
- [How to dereference typedef array pointer properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44575307/how-to-dereference-typedef-array-pointer-properly) - how to dereference a typedef-ed array and access its elements
- [typedef fixed length array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523497/typedef-fixed-length-array) - again how to format the typedef.

The last one in that list felt most relevant to me, as the accepted answer nicely states (emphasis mine)

> **[this form of typedef is] probably a very bad idea**

Which, having now tried to understand what's actually going on, I couldn't agree with more! Not least because it hides the type you're actually trying to work with...

### Notes

So after we started thinking on this, I did a bit of experimentation:

```
typedef uint8_t msgdata[150];
msgdata data = {0};
msgdata* pData = &data;
int main() {
    printf("%p\n", pData);
    printf("%p\n", *pData);
    printf("%p\n", &data);
    printf("%p\n", data);
    
    return 0;
}
Outputs:
0x6020a0 
0x6020a0 
0x6020a0 
0x6020a0
```

And if I extend that to include a suitable array, `arr` and a defined size value, `size`, I can use various memcpy calls such as

```
    std::memcpy(arr, data, size);
    std::memcpy(arr, pData, size);
    std::memcpy(arr, *pData, size);
```

Which all behave the same, leading me to believe they are equivalent.
I understand the first and last versions (`data` and `*pData`), but I'm still unsure of what is happening regarding the `pData` version...

Comment: The address of a standard-layout composite is the same as the address of its first member...

Comment: Imagine the typedef is changed tomorrow to `struct msgdata{ uint_8 data[150]; };`, what should you do so that your code is least affected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is, IMO, plain wrong. I'd also accept the alternative view "the code is very misleading"

```
//Included from library:
//typedef uint8_t msgdata[150];
//const msgdata* IRead_GetMsgData (void);

uint8_t mBuff[2048];
void Foo() {
    const msgdata* myData = IRead_GetMsgData();
    if(myData != nullptr) {
        std::memcpy(mBuff, *myData, sizeof(msgdata));
    }
}
```

When you dereference `*myData`, you mislead the reader. Obviously, memcpy requires a pointer to a `msgdata`, so the dereferencing star is not needed. `myData` is already a pointer. Introducing an extra dereference would break the code.

But it doesn't... Why?

That's where you specific use case kicks in. `typedef uint8_t msgdata[150];` msgdata is an array that decays into a pointer. So, `*msgdata` is the array, and an array is(decays into) a pointer to its beginning.

So, you could argue: no big deal, I can leave my extra `*` in, right ?

**No**.

Because someday, someone will change the code to:

```
class msgdata
{
    int something_super_useful;
    uint8_t msgdata[150];
};
```

In this case, the compiler will catch it but, in general, an indirection level error might compile to a subtle crash. It would take you hours or days to find the extraneous `*`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You are, of course, right - that makes a lot of sense. And the warning about the indirection is heeded!

Comment: Replacing the `memcpy` call with `std::copy_n`, also feels like a safer solution. In this case, the `msgdata*` needs to be de-referenced: `std::copy_n(*myData, sizeof(msgdata), mBuff);`. As I understand it, the de-reference in this case is safe (not only that, but required) as there is no risk regarding the re-definition of msgdata. If it is redefined to a type which is not compatible with `LegacyInputIterator` (such as the class in the example), the call to copy_n will fail to compile. Does this seem like a more sensible solution?

Comment: seems sensible, although I'm not familiar with copy_n. nice find :-)