# 'new' operator and typedef-ed arrays in C++

Tags: c++, new-operator, typedef

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to dynamically create an array of constant size in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339950/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-create-an-array-of-constant-size-in-c)

This is rather a theoretical question - I wonder why actually operator new[] in C++ returns pointer to first element of array and not actual array (or a pointer to it). This came to me while trying to do something like

```
typedef int int4[4];
int4* ni4 = new int4;
```

While I know why this does not work (although it wasn't so clear in the beginning ;)), it really bugs me that code, which in principle is `A* ptr= new A;` does not compile. Am I the only one that finds that weird?

Comment: Is it a typo or you really meant typedef int[4] int4; ?

Comment: @Eric: That's correct `typedef` syntax.  But there is a typo in the next line, should be `int4* ni4 = new int4;`

Comment: with int[4] int4 i get error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token; Second typo corrected

Comment: Hum didn't know we could typedef like this, good to know even if I may never use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I find strange here is that `operator new[]` is used.  The code tries to allocate a single instance of an aggregate, which would be legal if the aggregate was a `struct`.

But this is the behavior called out by the standard in section `[expr.new]`.

However, there's a very simple workaround:

```
typedef int int4[4];
int4* ni4 = new int4[1];
```

...

```
delete [] ni4;
```

Comment: This is really weird that this is standard behavior. Perhaps typedef of array is not treated as aggregate? Anyway, thanks for hint with workaround - it seems much better than `int4* ni4 =(int4*) new int4;` that i have been using. But still my question remains - why standard is made like that? I always thought that standard is aiming at full type correctness - this seems rather like violation...

Comment: Why would that be strange? The code tries to allocate an array, so the `operator new[]` is used. That's how the Standard specifies the semantics. The code that the guy shows is equivalent to `new int[4]`, which allocates with the exact same object type.

Comment: @Johannes: In `new int[4]`, the array specifier `[4]` is actually part of the grammar for the *new-expression*, it's not part of the type.  I would generally expect a *new-expression* having the optional *noptr-new-declarator* to call `operator new[]()`, and one without to call `operator new()`.  The current behavior which special-cases array types vs other aggregates makes it hard to write template code.

Comment: `int[4]` is a `new-type-id`, and specifies a type. If you use it as `new int[4]`, it tells the system that it should create an object of type `int[4]`. Surely the `[4]` is parsed by *some* grammar production. Everything is :) The rules are specified entirely in terms of "if an array object is created, call 'operator new[]', otherwise use 'operator new'". I too think that it's not entirely off to expect what you say though. `new T` certainly "looks different" than `new U[N]`. But from a language point of view, it's the same, when `T` is the type `U[N]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I understand your question. In C++, as in C, there is no difference between a pointer to the first element of an array and the array itself.

EDIT: As has been pointed out to me, this is not really correct - please forgive my mistake, I've been spending too much time with Java and C# recently ;-)

Comment: There certainly is a difference - they are different types. `sizeof` will give different results, and you can write functions that take references to arrays (of a particular size), but not pointers.

Comment: This is wrong, there is big difference. Array is not pointer, but in some cases it can be treated as pointer. Some of differences:1.different `sizeof` 2.different initialization

Answer (score 0):

It could probably be argued for the following

```
new (int[N]); // type int(*)[N]
new int[N]; // type int*
new T; /* T* */
```

Only in the middle case, `N` can be a runtime value. Nevertheless, the spec does not establish such a type difference. Arrays need special handling anyway in almost all cases (as in, you cannot just copy them either). So you should be prepared to handle them specially. For example, you also have to use `delete[]` instead of `delete` in your case.

Just to make it clear, if the above would be true, then you would need awkward syntax

```
int (*p)[N] = new (int[N]);
(*p)[N-1] = 0;
p[0][N-1] = 0; /* or, equivalently */
p[N-1] = 0; /* but not this, error! */
```

You would first need to dereference the array pointer.

Comment: or just `int *p= new int[N];` - if above is true;) but that depends on what do you need - eg. consider `(int[N])` as aggregate (with `struct { int f[N]; }` it would work as i want it to).

Comment: @j_kubik I don't understand what you mean with "consider (int[N]) as aggregate". `int[N]` itself is an aggregate. Arrays are aggregates.

Comment: That's what I mean - arrays are aggregates, but their semantics is different than say structures - if you create `new` structure, then returned pointer points to entire struct, not a part of it. In case of array I would expect pointer to array to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

It's legacy from C, which actually had it as legacy from B. The entire handling of native arrays in C++ is abysmal but they can't change it. This is the case for many problems in C++.